# convert repetitive variables and functions into loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

can anyone help me how to convert this into loops :) hi newbie here in javaScript:) the output of this is a input form, i want all the value that typed into the form to be appear instantly  by using keyup event thanks in advance :)

```
let textarea = document.querySelectorAll('span')
let bns = document.querySelector('#bns');
let id = document.querySelector('#id');
let img = document.querySelector('#img');
let lg = document.querySelector('#lg');

textarea.forEach(function (item, index) {
    item.classList.add('t'+ `${index}`)
    //console.log(item)
})

let input = addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    let strbns = bns.value;
    let strid = id.value;
    let strimg = img.value;
    let strblg = lg.value;
    document.querySelector('.t0').innerText = strbns
    document.querySelector('.t1').innerText = strid
    document.querySelector('.t2').innerText = strimg
    document.querySelector('.t3').innerText = strblg
});
```

output
[image]

i create variables to each input field and used the keyup event to print the out put to individual span. yes it works but its so repetitive and i thinks it is much better if it's convert it into for loops but i dont know how

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more optimal by give a try like this.

```js
const formData = {
  bns: document.querySelector('#bns'),
  id: document.querySelector('#id'),
  img: document.querySelector('#img'),
  lg: document.querySelector('#lg')
};

document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    Object.keys(formData).forEach((key, index) => {
    document.querySelector(`.t${index}`).innerText = formData[key].value
  })
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="bns"/>
<input type="text" id="id"/>
<input type="text" id="img"/>
<input type="text" id="lg"/>

<div class="t0"></div>
<div class="t1"></div>
<div class="t2"></div>
<div class="t3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two arrays which are the same length. Then you can loop over one of them with the index to get the corresponding element:

```js
const elements = [bns, id, img, lg];
const selectors = [".t0", ".t1", ".t2", ".t3"].map((s) => document.querySelector(s));

addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    elements.forEach((el, index) => {
        selectors[index].innerText = el.value;
    });
});
```